# Document_Open() falla cuando abro el documento por Macro vba en Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo un excel con el siguiente código vba:

```
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("Ruta") 'Ruta verificada
```

Y tengo un documento word con este código vba:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint).Show
End Sub
```

Si abro el word "a mano" todo funciona correctamente, pero si ejecuto la macro en el excel, despues de 40-50 segundos aparece este mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y sigue intentandolo... hasta que fuerzo el cierre del excel.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Has probado a ejecutarlo línea a línea con F8? ¿Te pasa lo mismo?

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes si.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, el código que tú estás ejecutando espera una respuesta del usuario, porque abre el cuadro de diálogo de opciones de impresoras y demás.

A mí tu código me da el mismo fallo, y lo he arreglado haciendo el Objeto Word Application visible:

```
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

objWord.Visible = True 'lo volvemos visible

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("Ruta") 'Ruta verificada
```

De esta manera, el código se queda esperando a que el usuario cierre el cuadro de diálogo. Cuando se cierre, el código de Excel seguirá ejecutándose.

Comment: Vale sí, me sirve. Justamente tenia puesta esa línea despues del objDoc. Pensaba que era algo sin sentido, hacer algo visible sin abrirlo, pero claro hablamos de otro objeto. Muchas gracias.